# How to increase performance with dictionary?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance, dictionary

my problem is, that i do not have the fastest performance in this code.
I have like 30 tests which i have to solve with this code but i only solve 28 till it throws an error because it took to long.

**Thats my example input:**

```
queryType: ["insert", "insert", "addToValue", "addToKey", "get"]
query: [[1,2], [2,3], [2], [1], [3]]
```

```
If queryType[i] === "insert" -> Add at query[i][0] value query[i][1].
If queryType[i] === "addToValue" -> Add query[i][0] to every value.
If queryType[i] === "addToKey" -> Add offset.
If queryType[i] === "get" -> Add query[i][0] to result value.
```

**Thats my current code:**

```
function testHashMap(queryType, query) {
    let hash = {};
    let result = 0;
    let offset = 0;
    let len = queryType.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        let querys = query[i][0];
        switch (queryType[i]) {
            case "insert": 
                hash[querys] = query[i][1];
                break;
            case "addToValue": 
                for (let key in hash) {
                    hash[key] += querys;
                }
                break;
            case "addToKey": 
                offset += querys;
                break;
            case "get": 
                result += hash[querys - offset];
                break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Does anybody have an idea how i can increase the speed of this function?
Thank you for your time!

Comment: `addToValue` takes too long.  The point of this exercise is to figure out how to produce the same effect without actually adding to every value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Matt Timmermans noted in the comments, one way to speed up might be not to actually add to every value. Let's say our starting values are

```
[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Now to add 3 to every element we record a general `offset`, 3.

Suppose we now get a single insert, `[2, 4]`. We would like to set the third element to 4 so we first subtract our offset. 4 - 3 = 1 so we actually don't change the third element at all!

Now we are requested to `get` the element at index 2. We add our general offset:

```
1 + 3 = 4
```

Just as expected.

This way, all updates are kept at `O(1)` time complexity, which should run significantly faster.

Comment: ```queryType: ["insert",  "insert", "addToKey",  "addToKey", "addToKey", "insert", "addToValue", "addToKey", "addToKey", "get"]
query: [[-5,-2], [2,4], [-1], [-3], [1], [3,-2], [-4], [-2], [2], [-8]]```
Now we have two times get, how does it work now?

Comment: @RoyBlunk not sure I follow. I see one `get` in your example but you said we have two times `get`. Please provide a complete example with expected output and I'll check it with my proposed method.

Comment: I think i forgot this. For example you have ["insert", "get", "insert", "get"], now you have two times where you have to add the value to result. But if you use the offset like you told me, there is no simple way to get the write value or isnt it?

Comment: @RoyBlunk something like this? Continuing from where element at index 2 was 4, we have `[1, 1, 1, 1], offset: 3`. Now a second insert, `[2, -6]`, so we set it to `(-6) - offset = -9`. The list is now `[1, 1, -9, 1`. Now we get 2 again and we have -9 + 3 = -6 as expected.

Comment: Maybe im looking for the wrong way, i'll try your way.

Answer (score 0):

A dispatch object may be faster if this is a hot spot in the code (as seems to be the case from your question):

```
function testHashMap(queryType, query) {
    let hash = {};
    let result = 0;
    let offset = 0;
    let len = queryType.length;
    const dispatch = {
        insert(i) {
            hash[querys] = query[i][1];
        },
        addToValue() {
            for (let key in hash) {
                hash[key] += querys;
            }
        },
        addToKey() {
            offset += querys;
        },
        get() {
            result += hash[querys - offset];
        }
    };
    for (let i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        let querys = query[i][0];
        (dispatch[queryType[i]] || () => {})(i);
    }
    return result;
}
```

This is because JavaScript engines are tuned to aggressively optimize object method/property lookup in hot spots.